# Change apk output folder in Gradle 4.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I would like to change the APK `output folder` and this is what I used to do:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def filePath = "${rootProject.rootDir.absolutePath}/apks/${variant.name}"
        println("My Path: " + filePath)
        outputFileName = filePath
    }
}
```

However, it didn't work in `Gradle 4.1` (Android studio 3.0 preview). Instead of generating the folder as the path above, it generated the above path inside old `debug` folder like image below:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Did the output directory change between `gradle` 3 and 4? 
`platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release.apk` and `platforms/android/build/outputs/release/android-release.apk`. This difference is breaking our builds and we're not sure if it is Gradle.

Answer (score 25):

This is a workaround to keep the output path same after upgrade to gradle 4.x.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "../" + outputFileName
    }
}
```

now apk is generated at platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release.apk

Comment: This is what I am looking for.

Comment: This stopped working after upgrading to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0`. Now the builder drops this warning and ignores location change: Setting outputFileName to '../../myfilename.apk' can result in incorrect behavior. Relative paths are not supported when setting an output file name. The outputFileName API supports changing the output file's name, but not its location.

Answer (score 22):

From [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output):

> Using the **Variant API** to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during build time, as shown below:

```
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }
```

> However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing **outputFile** objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means faster configuration times.

Comment: Thanks. But that means there's no way to do it, right? that sounds not really good to me.

Comment: None that I am aware of, sorry.

Comment: A dirty way to do it might be to move the files with a task after they've been built.

Comment: You could set a task to move the files to another location after build completion.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue, because I needed the output apk in a known folder and not in a folder depending on the computer user name. So I have fixed like this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def apk = output.outputFile;
        def newName = apk.name.replace(".apk", "-v" + variant.versionName + "-RELEASE.apk");
        newName = newName.replace("-" + variant.buildType.name, "");

        outputFileName = "./" + newName
    }
}
```

With this I get the apk in:
".../outputs/apk/flavorName/buildTypeName/xxx.apk"

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This solution worked for me - looks like it should be marked as the answer

Comment: This code throw an exception as "Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'output' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated" on Gradle v4.4. `output.outputFile` should be changed as `outputFileName`.

Comment: And last code will throw "Absolute path are not supported when setting an output file name."

Comment: I have edited the answer to work with the last version of gradle.